# Calculating the balance from the previous amount based on DATE?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table that has amounts transactions for each user. I am trying to query a table that also shows a 'balance' column.

[image]
So in the picture above, I have sorted by DATE, now, I would like another column that calculates the balance. So in balance column, starting with the last record (earliest record), it will start off with $150 on that row, then the next row will calculate the current amount - previous amount.

So it should look something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with a CTE for the data, you can use the [WINDOW FUNCTUON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html) version of SUM to get the result you want.

```
WITH data(number_id, value, date) AS (
    SELECT column1, column2, to_date(column3, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM VALUES
    (1, 10, '2022-01-01'),
    (1, 20, '2022-01-02'),
    (1, 30, '2022-01-04'),
    (1, 40, '2022-01-07'),
    (2, 110, '2022-01-01'),
    (2, 120, '2022-01-02'),
    (2, 130, '2022-01-04'),
    (2, 140, '2022-01-07')
)
SELECT number_id
    ,value
    ,sum(value)over(partition by number_id order by date rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as balance
    date
FROM data
ORDER BY 1, 4;
```

gives:

| NUMBER_ID | VALUE | BALANCE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 20 | 30 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1 | 30 | 60 | 2022-01-04 |
| 1 | 40 | 100 | 2022-01-07 |
| 2 | 110 | 110 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 120 | 230 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2 | 130 | 360 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2 | 140 | 500 | 2022-01-07 |

With your numbers (and `72` corrected to `-72`):

```
WITH data(number_id, value, date) AS (
    SELECT column1, column2, to_date(column3, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM VALUES
    (111, -22, '2021-12-24'),
    (111, 22, '2021-12-23'),
    (111, -10, '2021-12-22'),
    (111, -30, '2021-12-21'),
    (111, 5, '2021-12-20'),
    (111, -48, '2021-12-19'),
    (111, 5, '2021-12-18'),
    (111, -72, '2021-12-17'),
    (111, 150, '2021-12-16')
)
SELECT number_id
    ,value
    ,sum(value)over(partition by number_id order by date rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as balance
    ,date
FROM data
ORDER BY 1, 4 DESC;
```

gives:

| NUMBER_ID | VALUE | BALANCE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | -22 | 0 | 2021-12-24 |
| 111 | 22 | 22 | 2021-12-23 |
| 111 | -10 | 0 | 2021-12-22 |
| 111 | -30 | 10 | 2021-12-21 |
| 111 | 5 | 40 | 2021-12-20 |
| 111 | -48 | 35 | 2021-12-19 |
| 111 | 5 | 83 | 2021-12-18 |
| 111 | -72 | 78 | 2021-12-17 |
| 111 | 150 | 150 | 2021-12-16 |

Comment: @lalaland, check 2nd last row of your 'expected result: 'current amount - previous amount` would be 75-150=-78, but your are showing positive 78.

Comment: @userMT actually you are both wrong `150+72 = 222`

Comment: Haha, @simeon pilgrim, I was wrong because the second last row was +72 and not +75, but you had it as -72. We were all wrong, lol

Comment: The poster has a mistake in their math. It only takes one change to make the posters numbers work. Aka the sign of the 72 becoming negative. I was going to use the input as show in the picture, but thought the results being completely different might be more confusing than fixing the input. So it’s almost just wrong to expect lack of wrongness when it all starts with wrong math. You just happened to point at the wrong part of it and do an incorrect correction. @userMT

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! This helped so much. I have a similar question, now I need to calculate the  balance based on the difference of two amount columns. Would you be able to help with this problem as well?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911113/how-to-calculate-the-balance-on-the-difference-of-two-amount-columns-based-on-da